# Filter flat array where leading integer is found in another flat array

Tags: php, arrays, filtering, prefix, array-intersect

I need to intersect two arrays where the leading number of a given value is found in another array.

```
$A = [
    '104-20_140.1',
    '104-10_136.1',
    '104-40_121.1',
    '104-41_122.1',
    '200-42_951.1',
    '200-43_952.1',
    '200-44_123.1',
    '200-45_124.1',
    '300-46_125.1',
    '300-47_126.1', 
    '300-48_127.1',
    '300-49_128.1',
    '380-56_125.1',
    '380-57_126.1',
    '380-58_127.1',
    '380-59_128.1',
];

$B = ['200', '300'];
```

I need two look at Array A's beginning of the value. Ex. [0] => **104**-20_140 and see if the beginning '**104**' it exists in Array B. If not Array A shall remove it from the result array C.

The output with Array A and B should have:

```
[
     '200-42_951.1',
     '200-43_952.1',
     '200-44_123.1',
     '200-45_124.1',
     '300-46_125.1',
     '300-47_126.1',
     '300-48_127.1',
     '300-49_128.1',
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function startsWith($haystack, $needle) {
    $length = strlen($needle);
    return (substr($haystack, 0, $length) === $needle);
}

$C = array();
foreach ($A as $ka => $va) {
    foreach ($B as $kb => $vb) {
        if (startsWith($va, $vb)) {
            $C[] = $va;
        }
    }
}
```

[example on codepad](http://codepad.org/FlUMOHgh)

Comment: Thx I worked perfect.. The oly thing I needed to change was the return value in function startsWith() to return (substr($haystack, 0, $length) == $needle);

Answer (score 1):

Chances are, what you really need is array_uintersect. This will give the option to provide a custom callback which contains the logic on how to check if values intersect.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect.php

In the callback, you will need to parse out first section before the first "-" using substr or one of the preg functions.

Comment: This hint is missing its advised implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your input array by your flat whitelist array swiftly with linear time complexity by using a basic loop and only populating the result array with values where the whole leading integer is found in the whitelist.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZgaC1))

```
$whitelist = ['200', '300'];

$result = [];
foreach ($array as $v) {
    if (in_array(strstr($v, '-', true), $whitelist)) {
        $result[] = $v;
    }
}
var_export($result);
```